# How do i assert, compile time, that the nth element of a tuple is an optional of some type?

Tags: c++

I need to check if the nth element of a tuple is an optional of some type.
It has to be an std::optional and not a std::variant (which could have made the code simpler).

My first instinct is the following. But this throws a compiler error.

```
template<int N, typename TupleToCheck>
void StaticCheck() {
    using NthType = typename tuple_element<N, TupleToCheck>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<NthType, std::optional<NthType::value_type>>);
}
```

I suspect that this is because the compiler does not know if NthType could have a type `value_type` defined within it.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What error does this produce?

Comment: It works for me (no compilation errors) if I correct syntax errors: https://godbolt.org/z/dxndEx. Added `std::`, `typename `, and `::value`.

Comment: @DanielLangr yep that fixed it. so I guess compiler assumes any unknown variable is a value, but the keyword typename convinces it otherwise?

Comment: @Sway It is called a dependent name and yes, the compiler cannot distinguish whether it is a type or a value on its own, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for the sake of closure.

The issue with my code was syntax, as @DanielLangr pointed out in the comments.

> It works for me (no compilation errors) if I correct syntax errors: godbolt.org/z/dxndEx. Added std::, typename , and ::value.

The fixed code is as below

```
template<int N, typename TupleToCheck>
void StaticCheck() {
    using NthType = typename std::tuple_element<N, TupleToCheck>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<NthType, std::optional<typename NthType::value_type>>::value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the error, but this scheme should work for all templates regardless whether `::value_type` exists:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <optional>


template<typename T>
struct is_optional{
    constexpr static bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_optional<std::optional<T>>{
    constexpr static bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_optional_v = is_optional<T>::value;

template<int N, typename TupleToCheck>
void StaticCheck() {
    static_assert(is_optional_v<std::tuple_element_t<N,TupleToCheck>>);
}


int main(){

    using t1 = std::tuple<int,std::optional<double>,double>;

    StaticCheck<1,t1>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Quimby, this should work, but I believe the code with the fix by DanielLangr is simpler and more concise.

Comment: @Sway Definitely agree. He should make it an answer, even if it was basically just a typo.